# upgrade PHP from 5.3.3 to 5.3.8+ on windows

Tags: php, windows, installation

I have been using `PHP 5.3.3` for awhile and have customized many things in `php.ini` and added some extra extensions. how i can upgrade to `5.3.8+` without leaving installed extensions and `php.ini` configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make a backup of your php.ini and copy it over when you're done upgrading. As to extensions, if they're built-in extensions (or if you're using something like WAMP, XAMPP, or Zend Server that bundles the extensions you need) then you shouldn't need to do anything else, but if not then those extensions will need to be recompiled for the new version of PHP (make sure you download the latest release of the extension for PHP 5.3.x first). Many extensions can be installed using PECL, which makes things a bit easier.

Answer (score 1):

There is a directory called [`PHPRC`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/configuration) on your disk. Set it to the version you want to have actively supported.

Also take care that the windows %PATH% environment variable point to the PHP installation you want to use by default on the system if you want to use it in command-line-interface.

If you have a webserver configured, look into your websevers documentation how you specify the path to the PHP webserver module, Fast CGI Process manager or CGI executeable. It also needs to point to that path.

Alternatively to install into a new directory you can also rename the old PHP directory and create a new directory with the same name as the previous one. PHP configuration is based on ini-file, so you can have multiple versions on the same system next to each other easily.